# VB Script - If Then Statement

Tags: vbscript

Code isn't working.. suggestions?

```
Dim DevStat as string
IF [LandVal1] > 0 and [BUILDVAL1] = 0 then
  DevStat = "Undeveloped"

ElseIF [BUILDVAL1] > 0 and [LandVal1] = 0 then
  DevStat = “Developed”

ElseIF [BUILDVAL1] > 0 and [LandVal1] > [BUILDVAL1] then
  DevStat = “Underdeveloped”

ElseIF [BUILDVAL1] = 0 and [LandVal1] = 0
  DevStat = “Unknown”

Else
  DevStat = "none"
End if
```

Comment: Isn't this VBA, not VB Script?

Comment: At a minimum, (1) please indicate how this question is related to GIS and (2) explain exactly *how* the code is "not working."

Answer (score 2):

"You're missing a **then** on the next to last statement.

```
Dim DevStat as string 

IF [LandVal1] > 0 and [BUILDVAL1] = 0 then 
  DevStat = "Undeveloped"
ElseIF [BUILDVAL1] > 0 and [LandVal1] = 0 then 
  DevStat = "Developed"
ElseIF [BUILDVAL1] > 0 and [LandVal1] > [BUILDVAL1] then 
  DevStat = "Underdeveloped"
ElseIF [BUILDVAL1] = 0 and [LandVal1] = 0 THEN ' <-- you were missing this
  DevStat = "Unknown"
Else 
  DevStat = "none" 
End if
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Even with the edit, I'm still receiving a general error message..

Comment: What's the general error message, and what line is it on?

Comment: Edited response. Found special before and after quotes in the code, instead of generic quote ("). Copying and pasting the code should work now.